# File size differs when sending over UDP

Tags: file, sockets, udp

I am running into problems when I try to transfer a file between the simple server and client applications that I have written. The file gets transferred successfully, but the file size is different at the receiving side (server side). 
I open the file on the client side, use fseek() to find the size of the file. Then I use fread() to to read it into a buffer of char type. I send this buffer using sendto() as I have to use UDP sockets. 
On the server side, I use recvfrom() to store this and use fwrite() to write it into another file. But when I check the size of the file, it is much bigger. Also I am not able to open it even though it is supposed to be a text file. 
Can you give me some pointers as to where I might be going wrong? Also is this the best way to send files over sockets? Are there better methods to send files?

Thanks

Code for client side

```
//Writing code to open file and copy it into buffer
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
        size_t file_size = ftell(fp);
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        if(fread(file_buffer, file_size, 1, fp)<=0)
        {
            printf("Unable to copy file into buffer! \n");
            exit(1);
        }

        //Sending file buffer
        if(sendto(sock, file_buffer, strlen(file_buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, serv_len)<0)
        {
            printf("Error sending the file! \n");
            exit(1);
        }
        bzero(file_buffer, sizeof(file_buffer));
```

Code on the server side to receive the file

```
//Receiving file from client
        char file_buffer[BUFSIZE];
        if(recvfrom(sock, file_buffer, BUFSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &client_addr_size)<0)
        {
            printf("Error receiving file.");
            exit(1);
        }

        char new_file_name[] = "copied_";
        strcat(new_file_name,file_name);
        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen(new_file_name,"w+");
        if(fwrite(file_buffer, 1, sizeof(file_buffer), fp)<0)
        {
            printf("Error writing file! \n");
            exit(1);
        }
```

Comment: Use a `diff` tool to see *where* the files differ. Then use that knowledge to find out *where* the errors might be introduced: e.g. an off-by-one somewhere are entire packet-sized parts just skipped? Remember: **UDP provides no guarantee of packet delivery**, so if switching to TCP "solves" (or changes) the observed problem ..

Comment: What code are you using? Also, they don't call UDP the `Unreliable Datagram Protocol` for nothing. If at all possible it's probably best to just use a TCP connection.

Comment: @pst I am sure this problem is not brought about by use of UDP. I feel the error is in my implementation of opening, copying and transferring the file. I have sent only small file sizes to check my programs. The problem is even if I send 1 3 Kb file, it shows up as 30KB or 40KB.

Comment: @marinus I shall add the code I have written to my original question.

Comment: @Bararuloke Switch to TCP. Compare. Then use TCP or *reinvent* TCP-over-UDP. Some people like different colored wheels. I don't see a point here :)

Comment: @pst I will try TCP also. But I anyway have to come back to this since this is what is required for my project work. And using this as a foundation I need to build something similar to what you said - reinvent TCP over UDP - to make UDP reliable. Before I go for that, I need to make sure that I get atleast the basic issue of transferring files properly.

Comment: @Bararuloke So .. why not just use TCP? :) Anyway, this is a "common task" in introductory university-level network programming courses (it's more complex than just sending "received" replies to implement efficiently) ..

Comment: @Bararuloke You *can't* be sure it isn't due to UDP unless you have some kind of sequence number in the protocol and your code checks that you have received them all. Are you aware of (1) datagram loss (2) datagram redelivery (3) out of sequence delivery and (4) practical UDP datagram size limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

In the sender:

- How do you allocate `file_buffer`? What if the file is bigger than the buffer? (Probably this is not causing the problem at hand.)
- You only check to see if the return value from `fread` is `<= 0`. In fact, if an error or EOF occurs, the return value can be any value less than the full size of the file. (Probably this is not causing the problem at hand.)
- You pass `strlen(file_buffer)` instead of `file_size` to the `sendto` system call. `strlen` looks for NUL bytes which the file may or may not contain. It probably doesn't contain any, since you say it's a text file.

  - If the file contain at least one NUL byte the packet will be truncated before the first NUL byte and you will not transmit the full contents of the file.
  - If the file contains no NUL bytes, `strlen` will scan beyond the end of the file as read into the buffer. Either your program will crash because `strlen` scans into unallocated memory addresses, or you will send additional garbage past the end of the file.

In the receiver:

- You ignore the return value from `recvfrom` which is the length of the payload of the packet that was received. After that, there is no way for you to know how much data you received.
- When you `fwrite` the result, you pass `sizeof(file_buffer)` as the size instead of the actual amount of data that was received. This is a fixed value (`BUFSIZE`) which is probably bigger than your file. The file written on disk will contain garbage beyond the end of the file.

Comment: Very good but 'the return value can be any value less than the full size of the file' is only true if *EOF* occurs. If an error occurs the return value will be -1 and there will be an accompanying `errno`.

Comment: @Celada Thanks a lot. Such silly mistakes :(. I passed the `file_size` value on the client side and then used the value returned from the `recvfrom` call for my `fwrite`. Now everything works correctly. 
For now I am using a fixed size for my `file_buffer` , but like you said I might run into problems later on if the file is bigger than that. Right now I am just starting from the basics and learning by making the program more complex. So one of my next steps will be to break down whatever file is given and then send it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Celada I also noted down what you said regarding checking for the return value of `fread`. Will correct that also.